# Adding button when list is empty

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add the button dynamically when list is empty i.e no data to populate the list. I tried the below code and it not working

```
public class TableDemoActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

            Button test = new Button(this);
            test.setText("Hello Android");
            test.setId(5);
            test.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            linearLayout.addView(test);

        }

    }
```

Here is the layout file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TblLyt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/AcctHeader"
    >
    </TableRow>

    <ExpandableListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/BankExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="443dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.32"
    >
    </ExpandableListView>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Warpzit what do you mean by that?

Comment: Simply linearLayout.invalidate() after you've added it.

Comment: What wrong with this question ? I can see the downvote for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your button in xml layout file and do `visible` & `invisible` as per your condition

```
if(your condition)
{
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too and its working fine. But i need to add dynamically because button will occupy the space even it is hidden

Comment: please use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE ...it will not occupy space

Answer (score 2):

I solved your problem. Follow these steps. Your code is right but you have made a small mistake. You are adding your view or button in linear layout but your table layout is holding the entire area of your screen by using width and height being fill parent, so just add your button in table layout like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class TableDemoActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        TableLayout table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TblLyt);

        Button test = new Button(this);
        test.setText("Hello Android");
        test.setId(5);
        test.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        table.addView(test);        
        //linearLayout.addView(test);
    }
}
```

Now you can add button dynamically.

Comment: it works perfectly fine but the one which I accepted is most suitable solution in my case and also it was posted before you came up with answer. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's there, you just can't see it because of this:

```
<TableLayout  
    android:id="@+id/TblLyt" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

You are telling table to fill the entire layout.  You could set the TableLayout to GONE and then add the button, or you can change the `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I modified the height into wrap content but still its not visible.